# Postfix returning Invalid Addresses; 454 <to@domain.com>: Relay access denied

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, postfix-mta

I'm using a pre-configured Postfix server and interacting with it using JavaMail.  I am trying to send email notifications to any external domain that may request it.

Here is the java method to send a test email:

```
public void TestEmail() {

    String to = "to@domain.com";

    String from = "noreply@hostdomain.com";
    final String username = "user";
    final String password = "password";

    String host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
    });
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));

        message.setSubject("Test Email");

        message.setContent("This is a test email", "text/html");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("The test message was sent!");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

When I run the method that contains the JavaMail code, I get
    `generalError: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
        com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 454 4.7.1 <to@domain.com>: Relay access denied`

I was able to test outgoing mail from the Postfix server using
`echo "This is the body" | mail -s "This is the subject" to@domain.com`
and did receive the email in the testing inbox.

I'm not 100% sure what all the settings are on the Postfix server, but I am suspecting that is where the issue is, but I'm not familiar enough with it to start digging around and changing things all willy-nilly.

**EDIT:**
I removed the `Authenticator()` set up from the Session creation and replaced `Transport.send()` with recommended code block

```
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, 587, username, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
```

The entire new set of code is:

```
    String host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));

        message.setSubject("Test Email");

        message.setContent("This is a test email", "text/html");

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, 587, username, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();

        System.out.println("The test message was sent!");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

This has changed the error message I am receiving to: `Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?`

---

#### Solved

Solution: The Java code was not the issue.  The Postfix server was not configured to accept emails originating from a non-local IP/host. The IPs were added to the main.cf in the mynetworks variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](https://serverfault.com/questions/42519/how-to-correct-postfix-relay-access-denied) has more information.

First, get rid of the Authenticator as described in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  That will ensure that it's really trying to authenticate to the server.  Turn on [JavaMail session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to make sure it is authenticating.

Note that you can replace

```
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(host, 587, username, password);
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
```

with

```
    Transport.send(message, username, password);
```

You can get rid of the `mail.smtp.auth` setting, but keep the other properties.

Make sure you're using the [most current version of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

If it still doesn't work, the article above may provide some clues as to how to change the Postfix configuration.

Comment: Thanks! I made the changes as recommended from the JavaMail FAQ, and I am using the most current version of JavaMail, 1.5.6.  I at least get a different error message now; Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? So I'll see what I can figure out from there. Thanks again!

Comment: Update your post with the code you're currently using.  The error message says that you're connecting with SSL to a server port that is using plain text, not SSL.  The code above looks correct (it's using starttls) so you must've changed something else.

Comment: The code looks right.  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've implemented the suggestions you made, and it seems to be working as Java code.  It appears that the Postfix server was not configured to trust any external IPs, and as a result would not forward to the external address as an anti-spam measure.